# License file issue with SDL Web 8

Tags: web8

Getting below Error while browsing CMS. Though i have valid Web 8 Developer License which i received from SDL support team. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the real problem was license file itself.
I replaced my license file with new license and problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Open the licence file and look for the hostname see if its the same as your machine name.if not please check with tridion support.

Comment: i never gave them machine name or any other credentials for SDL Web 8, Don't think that "Developer Licenses" for Web 8 are machine specific.

Comment: Yes you are right developer licence is free for web 8 http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/q/403/401 please checj this post might be useful or email tridion support or provide them with logs if you see any errors  apart from the screen shot you provided.

Comment: If the license you received from support has a machine name in it, then there was a mistake in the license. Dev licenses do not have machine names.

Comment: Should i raise another request for Web 8 license with Machine name?